# String can't be parsed into UInt32

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am programming a Login for users in Unity. I have 2 "Text Mesh Pro UGUI" input fields for a username and a password.

I need to convert the username (which is a number) into an UInt32 to handle the Login of the User.

But there is a Problem with this simple string → UInt32 parsing.

This is the code:

```
// Note: I have tried typing different Numbers into the input field but in this case, 
// I have tried the same as the test_string (123456)

// This works perfect
string test_string = "123456";

UInt32 test_UInt32 = 0;

if (UInt32.TryParse(test_string, out test_UInt32))
{
    test_UInt32 = UInt32.Parse(test_string);
}

// This never works
UInt32 username_UInt32 = 0;

if (UInt32.TryParse(username.text, out username_UInt32))
{
    username_UInt32 = UInt32.Parse(username.text);
}

// Debugging for me to find the error
Debug.Log(username.text); // Output: 123456
Debug.Log(test_string);   // Output: 123456

Debug.Log(username.text.GetType().ToString());   // Output: System.String
Debug.Log(test_string.GetType().ToString());     // Output: System.String

Debug.Log(username.text.Length.ToString());      // Output: 7
Debug.Log(test_string.Length.ToString());        // Output: 6

// For Testing only => FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
username_UInt32 = UInt32.Parse(username.text);
```

Comment: Clearly, whatever is in `username.text` does not represent an unsigned integer number. Note that any spaces in a string, or an empty string for that matter, are not tolerated by UInt32.TryParse/UInt32.Parse. Also, `UInt32.TryParse` will parse the string (if it can be parsed) and stuff the result in the given Uint32 variable; thus the calls of `UInt32.Parse` inside the `if` blocks are just redundant, repeating what UInt32.TryParse already did...

Comment: @elgonzo Hi, thanks for the fast reply. The problem is: I can't find out what makes my string an incorrect format. If I log the string to the console it is the same as my test_string. I also logged it like: "|" + username.text + "|" => |123456| to be shure that there are no other chars . I also tried .Trim(). But still the same error.

Comment: @elgonzo Thats exactly what I think. but I can't find anything. And I also have no idea what to debug more. I have logged the strings itself to the console and also the Types of them. Is there anything I can do more to find the differences between the username.text string and the test_string string?

Comment: The lengths are different... is there a non-printable or zero-width character at the front or back of the string (it could just be null termination...)?  For sanity sake, does the username.text.GetType() say it is a string?

Comment: @JonathonK This is a good question. I have also noticed the differences in length. But I had no idea how this info can help me.
Is there a way to find out if there is such a character at the start or end of the string?

Comment: In your logs the length of both strings are different, this might indicate that the username one might have a special character somewhere. I would say that using `Trim()` would fix it, but can you print each charterer just to make sure this suspicious make sense, something like this would do it: `foreach(var charInfo in username.text.Select((c, index) => string.Format("[{0}]: '{1}' (char code: {2}", index, c, (int) c))) { Debug.Log(charInfo); }`

Comment: Also there is no point in parsing a second time with `UInt32.Parse` inside the `if (UInt32.TryParse(test_string, out test_UInt32))`, as `TryParse` already assigns the result to `test_UInt32`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The UInt32.Parse was just get the exception.

Comment: To get the exception you would have to negate the condition `if (!UInt32.TryParse(test_string, out test_UInt32)) ...`. Note the `!`. Or simply use `Parse` without a preceding `TryParse`. The purpose of `TryParse` is precisely to avoid the exception.

Comment: I'm no expert at Unity but does your text field have an AcceptsReturn property and is it set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all this input, it is working as expected now!

You were right, there was a hidden character.

This solved the problem:

```
string clean_string = username.text.Replace("\u200B", "")
```

With this cleaned up string, the parsing worked perfectly.

You saved my day. Wish you all the best!

Comment: Caveat: You're modifying things like "username", so you're potentially creating login issues for your users. Since you're handling it on the "back end" the assumption here is that your front end isn't validating such.

Answer (score 1):

look your lengths are different. you are missing something that you need to debug

```
  Debug.Log(username.text.Length.ToString());      // Output: 7
  Debug.Log(test_string.Length.ToString());        // Output: 6
```

`UInt32.Parse` Method only Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit unsigned integer equivalent. there must be a special character. Whitespace can appear at the beginning and at end but not between.

Answer (score 0):

probably there is white space character in  `username.text`
you can remove that white spaces with this code

```
username.text = username.text.Trim();
```

then parse it.

and when you use TryParse method there is no need to use Parse again. just change code to this

```
if (!UInt32.TryParse(username.text, out username_UInt32))
{
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried .Trim() but unfortunatelly still the same.

Comment: do a for or foreach on username.text characters and print every char . then you can find that extra char

Answer (score 0):

You are failing to realize the `.TryParse()` will not only tell you that whether the parse is successful but will fill the out parameter with the new number. You keep trying to assign a value to that parameter.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test_string = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        if (!uint.TryParse(test_string, out uint test_UInt32))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
            return;
        }
        if (!UInt32.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out uint username_UInt32))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Print($"The input string is {test_string}, the resulting number is {test_UInt32}, of type {test_UInt32.GetType()}");
        //Output  The input string is 1234, the resulting number is 1234, of type System.UInt32
        Debug.Print($"The input string is {textBox1.Text}, the resulting number is {username_UInt32}, of type {username_UInt32.GetType()}");
        //Output  The input string is 1234, the resulting number is 1234, of type System.UInt32
    }
```